# how can i add custom properties to javascript string object

Tags: javascript, string

i want to define my own custom properties for string object .so that i can use this properties directly on string objects. eg:- str is my string object.then i should be able to use `.IsNull` property as shown below.

```
var str = “string”;

str.IsNull; //returns true if null

str.IsEmpty; returns true if empty
```

Comment: A string can't be `null` (strings and `null` are different types).

Comment: C# allows null string.thanks didn't know this that js don't have null strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to all of you for your help.but i got the way

```
Object.defineProperty( String.prototype, 'IsNullOrEmpty', {
    get: function () {
        return ((0 === this.length) || (!this) || (this === '') || (this === null));
    }
});

var str = "";
str.IsNullOrEmpty;//returns true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can explore [**prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) property

For example

```
String.prototype.yourMethod = function(){
 // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Please note that you can't check if a string is `null` with a method in the `String` prototype, because the type would be `null` and not `String`.

Comment: But your example adds a method; the OP is trying to add properties (or perhaps getter methods that seem like properties to the client code).

Comment: why can't string be null in js?

Comment: @PawanWagh Because `null` is a type just like `string`. It cannot be of both types at the same time. It's eigher a string, maybe an empty one, or it is null (or undefined, which is something else too)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a new method to a String wrapper object's prototype. The best practice is to check if the method already exists before declaring it. For instance:

```
String.prototype.yourMethod = String.prototype.yourMethod || function() {
    // The body of the method goes here.
}
```

Comment: I don't see how "checking" if the method exists helps if you then just proceed blindly on the assumption that the pre-existing method will work exactly the same way as the one you're trying to add. (Should be fine if polyfilling standard JS methods for older browsers, but could go horribly wrong for custom methods.)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally make functions for this instead of extending the prototype.

If you extend the prototype, you have to make sure you add them to all types you want to check, it goes beyond the `String` object.

```js
function isNull(str) {
  console.log( str === null );
}

function isEmpty(str) {
  console.log( typeof str == 'string' && str === '' );
}


isNull(null);
isNull('');
isNull('test');

isEmpty(null);
isEmpty('');
isEmpty('test');
```